# Which grasp planner to use, manipulation pipeline, non PR2 robot

Tags: ros, grasping, arm-navigation, planner, manipulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(This question/answer thread was started via email)

I am trying to implement the ROS Manipulation Pipeline (perception + grasping) on our own robot. 
So it's a non PR2, with non-PR2 gripper.

**Original questions:**

- How do I define a non-PR2 gripper in the YAML config for use with "probabilistic_grasp_planner" or "bayesian_grasp_planner"? 
  e.g. see 
   */pr2_object_manipulation/trunk/manipulation/pr2_gripper_grasp_planner_cluster/config/pr2_gripper_model.yaml*

- If using a non-PR2 robot, don't I need a Grasp Planner to make the Pipeline work?

- or alternatively, I would need to setup the system to generate a database of grasps using GraspIt, like was done for the PR2 gripper?

Thanks,
David.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51691/which-grasp-planner-to-use,-manipulation-pipeline,-non-pr2-robot/) by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1103 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-01-10**:
This is a great question I've been trying to figure out myself as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The probabilistic planner is actually not a stand-alone planner - what it does is aggregate suggestions from other planners in a smart way. So if you have no planners for your gripper yet, it would not be the right place to start.

What does your hand look like? If it's at all gripper-like (or has a finger configuration that can be made to resemble a gripper), an adaptation of the PR2 Cluster Planner is definitely doable.

Installing the database on your system and hand-saving a few grasps in it should also be a few hours or maybe a day's worth of work.

Also note that the grasping pipeline relies on a lot of underlying software, in particular in terms of perception and arm navigation for operation. Are you also bringing up those components on your robot?

---

Originally posted by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) with karma: 586 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2013-01-10**:
Thanks Matei. I'll have a look at defining a gripper to adapt the cluster planner. Correct, yes I'm adapting PR2's Interactive Perception and Interactive Manipulation packages, to pick'n'place objects on a table.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look in the config folder in the pr2_gripper_grasp_planner_cluster package, you can see the config files I made for the Schunk hand and for the RobotIQ hand (as well as the one for the PR2).  If you want to use the cluster planner, you just have to make one for your hand--it specifies axis-aligned boxes (relative to the frame you want the pose for when defining a grasp in the world, which for the PR2 is the wrist roll link frame) that denote spaces where there shouldn't be any points (because your hand takes up that space) and space where there should be points (because that means there's something inside your hand).  And a few other params whose explanation is in the code.
(Sorry there isn't better documentation.  If you need help with that, just email.)

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2013-01-10**:
Thanks hsiao. Hopefully a simple configuration for a 1 or 2 DOF pincer/gripper will yield some results.